# How to add content-type header application/json to void postmapping endpoint?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, post, content-type

I have an endpoint like this:

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/notifications", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class NotificationController {

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void sendNotification(...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

While testing with pact tests I noticed that the api does not return "application/json" as Content-Type header. What should I do so it does?

Comment: Which content-type it returns instead?

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/api/notifications", headers = "Accept=application/json, Content-type=application/json") . this should work for you

Comment: You can't have `void` as `application/json` Content-Type, return some object with meaningful data and you will get the  `application/json` header

Answer (score 0):

Try this one instead

```
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Void> sendNotification(...) {
        ...
      return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).build();
    }
```

If this does not return by default Application/Json then you can do

```
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
```